# updating a nested adapter does not update UI

Tags: android

I have a `Fragment` that contains a `ListView` that uses a custom adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter`. Each item in this list view, contains another `ListView` that also extends `ArrayAdapter`. Think of it as a list of news stories and each news story having multiple images.

I now want to add a new image to a news story. What I do is:

```
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter =
         newsAdapter.getImageAdapterForNewsItem(id);
    imageAdapter.add(imageId);
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This all happens in `SelectImagesFragment`, where as the news items are listed in the `NewsItemsFragment`. However, the `SelectImagesFragment` contains a reference to the `NewsItemsFragment`. The above code executes in an AsyncTask, and before it executes, I move the user back to the `NewsItemsFragment`.

I was expecting the news list to get updated, once the AsyncTask completes and the UI to get refreshed. However, this is not happening. Since the `ImageAdapter` is inside the `NewsAdapter`, do I need to somehow tell the NewsAdapter that there has been a data change as well? If so, how do I do this? Calling 'notifyDataSetChanged()' won't work, since I didn't modify the underlying list data in `NewsAdapter` using `add()`.

Comment: need source code) you can just put your code in OnCreate and adding items does not call it.

Comment: @anil Not sure I understood your comment. I have verified that the above code gets executed. Also, when I move to a new view and and come back, the new images is visible. So it is just that the notify call is not getting picked up. Does `getView` of `NewsAdapter` need to get called for the underlying `ImageAdapter` update to be visible?

Comment: Would you consider using a different adapter? ArrayAdapter uses two lists since it's mostly used to be able to filter results. So when you add items your items will be added in the second (unfiltered list), and that's why your list won't update when first calling a notifyDataSetChanged().